# Can't access Facebook account registered under my e-mail address

Tags: privacy, facebook

I have two e-mail addresses: `email1@domain.com` and `email2@domain.com`.

I have a Facebook account that I can log into using `email2@domain.com`.

I recently got an email on `email1@domain.com` like the one below. It was addressed to someone other me.

[image: email]

It seems someone created a Facebook account with `email1@domain.com`. I have no idea if they had to have gotten access to `email1@domain.com` at some point or not.

Since `email1@domain.com` is, well, mine, I reset the password and gained access to this account.

Before I could delete it, which was my intent, I was forwarded to https://www.facebook.com/checkpoint/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F and I got a screen that looks like this:

[image: confirm_id]

I am unable to move past this identity check because I don't want to give Facebook any documents that pertain to me.
Moreover, the Facebook account isn't really mine, so it's not like I could even confirm the identity of whoever created it.

After navigating Facebook's Help Center and not finding anything useful, I googled how to get in touch with them and after navigating an irrelevant path of options, I was able to message them using my Facebook account.

Their response was basically that that channel was meant to address different kinds of issues and that I should find help in the Help Center. I replied (through email) that there's nothing for me in the Help Center. We exchanged about three messages each like this, until they shut me down by saying that the e-mail address I was replying to isn't being monitored.

How do I get rid of this account? What's the next best thing I can do? What else should I be worried about?

Comment: While it is bad that Facebook was not able to help you we have even more ways to help you with a Facebook account than Facebook itself, i.e. off-topic.

Comment: Such question if off-topic on this site.

Comment: So, someone created a Facebook account and used your email by mistake. Trying to take over the account could be deemed illegal, and just because they used your email does not make the Facebook account "yours" to get rid of. Work with Facebook to have your email removed from this account.

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like one of two options:

1. Someone has made an account with your email without verifying it - in which case, Facebook may (hopefully) have an expiration on the email verification and would automatically delete the account.
2. Someone has gained access to your email and has created a verified account - in which case, since deleting the account seems impossible, I would set a strong password for it, forget about it and worry about securing your email.